# Inserting from remote sql server to local mysql server

Tags: java, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbc_test {
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded sql server");
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded mysql");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("not loaded");
        }

            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://172.*.*.*:1433;" +"databaseName=Interface;user=user;password=pwd";
            String connectionUrl2="jdbc:odbc:Occupancy_Mysql";
            Connection con=null;
            Connection con2=null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;


            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                System.out.println("CONNECTED sql server");           
               con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl2);
               System.out.println("CONNECTED2 mysql");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
             stmt = con.createStatement();
             rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * FROM [Interface].[dbo].[VwZoneCount]");
              System.out.print("Select executed");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



           try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String zoneName = rs.getString("Zone Name");
                   int zonecount = rs.getInt("Zone Count");
                    String phasename = rs.getString("Phase Name");



                    String insertSql = "insert into occupancy.occupancy_phase_2(ZoneName,ZoneCount,PhaseName,time_stamp)values('"+zoneName+"',"+zonecount+",'"+phasename+"',now())";                  
                   pstmt = con2.prepareStatement(insertSql);
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                                        }
                    while(rs.next())
                    {

                        System.out.print(rs.getString("Zone Name")+"\t");
                        System.out.print(rs.getInt("Zone Count")+"\t");
                        System.out.println(rs.getString("Phase Name"));




                    }

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("out insert done");

             }
}
```

I am trying to insert the data from remote sql server to local mysql . The insert was happening at first , but now its not happening ,can you tell me where exactly is the code wrong .

The **while block** where i am printing on the console itself is not getting executed .

Comment: If while block is not getting executed, it means resultset does not return anything. Have you checked that?

Comment: Which `while`block? Do the queries return anything when run manually in Squirrel/TOAD/SQLServer client tool?

Comment: try to save the data of the first consult in an array and then past that data to the other insert, i find a similar problem doing something similar to you, my database crashed because i dont close and i mantein open a lot of time doing opperations in toher database for that i think is better save all data in a database closign that database and then doing the operations of the second database.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I checked, resultset is returning values but when i printed it was showing only one row data multiple times . IS MY SELECT STATEMENT RIGHT ??

Answer (score 1):

As your code stands now, only one row will get inserted into mysql.  The second while loop is looping on the select statement's result set.  So when it gets there it is just going to exhaust the result set outputting the second, third and so on results.

If that while block is not being executed then you might only have one row that matches the select statement.

Comment: But none of the row is getting inserted . Can you provide corrected code as per your suggestion